# Segmentation fault в Qt при передаче указателя на QGraphicsItemGroup через сигнал

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene

С начала поясню суть программы, извините за длинну, мне кажется так будет проще. Есть класс GameScreenWidget который совмещает в себе QGraphicsView и QGraphicsScene одновременно. GameScreenWidget имеет слот, в параметрах которог передается QGraphicsItemGroup*, и сигнал об нажатии клавиши в параметрах которого передается номер сигнала. Есть класс TestProgram который принимает номер нажатой клавиши и отправляет QGraphicsItemGroup*. Но таких TestProgram несколько(в конкретном случае 2) и для их связи есть класс ConnectBuffer в полях которого есть номер конкретной программы и при получении сигнала от GameScreenWidget он решает в какую программу оно должно отправится и передает это значение через функцию в TestProgram. Примерно так работает и передача QGraphicsItemsGroup*, но в другую сторону. При нажатии клавиши Tab ConnectBuffer должен менять номер текущей программы на соотвецтвующий, но тут вылезает проблема. При первой смене программы все идет как надо но во второй раз программа вылетает. Вот несколько функций:

Тут TestProgram возвращает группу из графических обьектов которые она содержит(одного). При ошибке дебагер указывает на эту функцию, а именно на момет вызова addToGroup(i).

```
QGraphicsItemGroup *TestProgram::ReturnGroupOfGraphicsItems()
{    
    QGraphicsItemGroup *g = new QGraphicsItemGroup();
    g->addToGroup(i);
    return g;
}
```

Вот функция передачи в ConnectBuffer:

```
void ConnectBuffer::SendNewGraphicsItemsGroup()
{
    std::cout << "Connect buffer Send new Group" << std::endl;


    switch (numberOfCurrentProgram)
    {

        case 1:
            pointerToScreenWidget->AddGroupOfItems(p1->ReturnGroupOfGraphicsItems());
        break;

        case 2:
            pointerToScreenWidget->AddGroupOfItems(p2->ReturnGroupOfGraphicsItems());
        break;
    }
}
```

И функция в GameScreenWidget которая принимает группу обьектов и "устанавливает" их в QGraphicsScene:

```
void GameScreenWidget::AddGroupOfItems(QGraphicsItemGroup *g)
{
    std::cout << "Game Screen Widget Add Group Of Items" << std::endl;


    graphicsScene.clear();
    graphicsScene.addItem(g);
    graphicsScene.update();
}
```

В ней есть одна особенность. Если убрать функцию очистки сцены программа будет работать корректно, но надписи из передаваемых обьектов будут накладыватся одна на друную. За сменой работающей прогаммы слежу по выводу консоли.

Может кто знает как решить проблему?

Comment: Что за переменная `i` в первом блоке кода? Очевидно же, что проблемы либо с `g`, либо той неизвестной переменной.

Comment: В приведенном коде  явно допущена ошибка. addToGroup принимает QGraphicsItem * item. Я думаю что вы вставили свой код кусками так что пожалуйста добавьте полностью код функции ReturnGroupOfGraphicsItems. Вообще такое может быть из за того что где то не вызываться диструктор.

Comment: MrBin, i - это QGraphicsTextItem* кототорый является единственным элементом группы g

Comment: Антон, это полный код функции. И в моем коде addToGroup принимает QGraphicsTextItem*  как и положено. Насколько я понял, QGraphicsItem это абстрактный класс и при передаче обьектов которые от него наследуются в параметрах функции оно будет восприниматся как передача  QGraphicsItem. И можно подробней по поводу вызова деструктора?